# Error Execute TaskAction

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy comenzando con la programación de android con lenguaje **kotlin** en **android studio** y tengo un error el cual no he podido encontrar solución.

Al momento en el que le doy run al proyecto me lanza error en el `Execute TaskAction`. Trato de ejecutarlo directo a mi celular, sin utilizar el emulador.
me pasa tanto en proyectos de terceros abiertos como en proyectos creados en el Android Studio.

- la version de **android studio** es 3.4.1
- **android gradle plugin** 3.4.0
- version de **gradle** 5.1.1

les agradecería mucho si pudiesen ayudarme para poder avanzar.

**Captura del Error**

[image: Este es el error que me aparece después de darle a run]

Este es el **código** de la app que baje de un repositorio para probar mi problema.

**Código del Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //the compression of webp file during build causes problem with FileDescriptor in ContentProvider.
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "webp"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.samplestickerapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        def contentProviderAuthority = applicationId + ".stickercontentprovider"
        // Creates a placeholder property to use in the manifest.
        manifestPlaceholders =
                [contentProviderAuthority: contentProviderAuthority]
        // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
        buildConfigField("String",
                "CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY",
                "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\"")
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/*/libnative-imagetranscoder.so'
        exclude 'lib/*/libnative-filters.so'
    }

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    // see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
//    splits {
//        abi {
//            enable true // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
//            universalApk true // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
//        }
//    }
}

task checkDebug {
    doLast {
        println("checkDebug")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.whatsapp")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.whatsapp, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle");
        }
        checkApplicationIdInDebug()
    }
}

private void checkApplicationIdInDebug() {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ignoreApplicationIdCheck = properties.getProperty('ignoreApplicationIdCheck')
    if (ignoreApplicationIdCheck == null) {
      /*  if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.equals("com.example.samplestickerapp")) {
            throw new GradleException("Your applicationId is currently com.example.samplestickerapp, please change your applicationId to a different string in app/build.gradle in line 10");
        }*/
    } else {
        println("application id check ignored")
    }
}


task checkRelease {
    doLast {
        println("checkRelease")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.example")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.example, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle");
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    println(task.name)
    if (task.name.contains("assembleDebug")) {
        task.dependsOn checkDebug
    }
    if (task.name.contains("assembleRelease")) {
        task.dependsOn checkRelease
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:1.13.0'
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Al parecer el error esta en la version del **plugin del gradle.**
Para poder resolverlo Edite el archivo **buil.gradle(Project: Android)** el cual tenia la version en 3.4.0 y la edite a 3.3.0.

**Código Editado**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: Añade el código del gradle para ver las librerías que estas usando

Comment: Hola, acabo de agregar el **código** del gradle de la app que estoy probando.

Comment: No acabo de verlo este error me ha salido varias veces y siempre lo he sacado metiendole hora y probando cual es la dependencia que me esta dando problemas

Comment: Hola amigo, muchas gracias por responder.
Encontré la solución y se trataba solo de cambiar la version del gradle en el archivo **Buil.Gradle** 
Editare mi pregunta para ponerlo mejor.